# Debugging the Linux Kernel on Boot

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have compiled the Linux kernel with configuration options for `ROOT_NFS`. My problem now is the screen prints to fast for me the see the error and I cannot find any documentation on the best approach to solve this problem. I am performing this in VirtualBox.

Comment: There is are boot parameters to do this. `boot_delay` especially.  See [kernel-parameters.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt)

Answer (score 0):

There is `Documentation/serial-console.txt` you could look into. Serial console has traditionally been used for debugging linux boot problems, where you then can save all of the screen capture on a different pc. This should be possible for a virtualbox use case as well, although I do not know how difficult it will be to configure serial access.

Comment: VirtualBox does have a virtual serial device that I can access through putty since I am on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The `dmesg` command prints the kernel's circular log buffer.  Your messages may be in there.